# Prove that $x^{y^x}>y^{x^y}$ for $x>y>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

Let $x>y>0$. Prove that $$x^{y^x}>y^{x^y}.$$
My attempts:

1. Let $1>x>y>0$.

In this case it's enough to prove that $$y^x<x^y$$ or
$$x\ln\frac{1}{y}>y\ln\frac{1}{x},$$ which is obvious;

2. $x\geq1>y>0$.

In this case our inequality is obviously true;

3. $e\geq x>y>1.$.

We need to prove that $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=x\ln{y}-y\ln{x}+\ln\ln{x}-\ln\ln{y}.$$
Now, $$f'(x)=\ln{y}-\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x\ln{x}}.$$
Let $h(y)=\ln{y}-\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x\ln{x}}.$

Thus, $$h'(y)=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}>0,$$ which says
$$h(y)>h(1)=-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x\ln{x}}=\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x\ln{x}}\geq0.$$
Id est, $f$ increases and
$$f(x)>f(y)=0;$$
4. $x>y\geq e$.

Since $$\left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\right)'=\frac{1-\ln{x}}{x^2}\leq0$$ for all $x\geq e,$ we obtain:
$$f(x)=xy\left(\frac{\ln{y}}{y}-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\right)+\ln\ln{x}-\ln\ln{y}>0;$$
5. $x\geq e>y>1.$

In this case I am stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: A forum https://math.stackexchange.com is a right place for such type questions.

Comment: @user64494 It was there and it's unsolved there.

Comment: Try setting x =y^t for t > 1; I think you will have an easier time of it when y is bigger than 1.  This is the wrong forum for your question.  Gerhard "Likes Simplifying With Term Rewriting" Paseman, 2019.03.08.

Comment: Present it at MSE as a featured question.

Comment: @user64494 I thought about this, but I want to see before, that in this forum can not  help me.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman I tried and it gives the same troubles. But thank you!

Comment: Please provide the link when you crosspost.

Comment: This problem has a strong flavor of Olympiad, rather than research, mathematics. Yet, it seems very non-trivial to me, and there have been many other Olympiad-style problems posted and accepted at this site. I vote to re-open, and I'd be happy if somebody of those voted to close (or anybody else) would post a solution.

Comment: Duplication of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136504/proof-that-pqp-qpq-for-pq1-in-use-of-derivatives/3137317#3137317 .

Comment: Dear  @user64494 it's exactly which I said. It's unsolved there. What is your proof of this inequality? Thank you!

Comment: Your proof is finished by making use of CASes (see my answer).

Comment: In my opinion it's not a proof. I look for a proof without computer. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Now I have a proof. Thanks all!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg In view of Seva's support and request, please consider posting your proof.

Comment: I am ready @Todd But for this we need to open this topic. I don't want to post something very nice and wait, when this solution will be deleted. I hope you'll understand me.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Sorry; you're right -- I overlooked the fact it had been closed. But perhaps add to your answer at Math.SE?

Comment: @Todd Trimble♦ I posted it yesterday here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136504

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Maple helps you in your case 5 through

```
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(x^(y^x)-y^(x^y), {x >= exp(1), y >= 1, y <= exp(1)});
```

> [1.71828182845907, [x = 2.71828182845907, y = 1.], 174]

Addition. Mathematica confirms it by

```
NMinimize[{x^(y^x) - y^(x^y),  x >= Exp[1] && y >= 1 && y <= Exp[1]}, {x, y}]
```

> {1.71828,{x->2.71828,y->1.}}

Comment: Why do you think that it helps? I don't think so.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: The above results prove the inequality for your case 5: 1.71 is   greater than zero. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: These programs can get us a bug, which happens in very many cases. I think it's not a proof.